# Melt pandas data with multi-level header?

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with 4 header rows. Like this:

```
A01     A01     A01     A01     A01     A01
1       1       1       2       2       2
Mon     Mon     Mon     Tue     Tue     Tue
# Beverages     # Appliances    Avg. brewing duration   # Beverages     # Appliances    Avg. brewing duration
Americano       549     46      "101,5" 542     38
ApplianceOffRinsing     28.718  673     "52,6"  28.718  665
ApplianceOnRinsing      35.381  682     "180,8" 35.308  676
CafeAuLait      112     16      "124,4" 99      10
```

How can I melt it in pandas?

I have read it in like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], delimiter='\t')
```

And now it looks like this:

[image]

I would like output data that looks like this:

```
A01  1   Mon   # Beverages    549
A01  1   Mon   # Applicances  46
...
```

with column names that I set.

I know it's something like `pd.melt(df, col_level=0, id_vars=['A'], value_vars=['B'])`, but I am not sure how to adapt this for my use case, especially since my data doesn't have column names.

Adding sample data now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem first column should be index, because only text column.

So in output get mixed numeric and text data:

```
df2 = df.melt(var_name=['a','b','c','d'], value_name='e')
print (df2)
      a  b    c                    d                    e
0   A01  1  Mon           #Beverages            Americano
1   A01  1  Mon           #Beverages  ApplianceOffRinsing
2   A01  1  Mon           #Beverages   ApplianceOnRinsing
3   A01  1  Mon           #Beverages           CafeAuLait
4   A01  1  Mon          #Appliances                  549
5   A01  1  Mon          #Appliances               28.718
6   A01  1  Mon          #Appliances               35.381
7   A01  1  Mon          #Appliances                  112
8   A01  1  Mon  Avg.brewingduration                   46
9   A01  1  Mon  Avg.brewingduration                  673
10  A01  1  Mon  Avg.brewingduration                  682
11  A01  1  Mon  Avg.brewingduration                   16
12  A01  2  Tue           #Beverages                101,5
13  A01  2  Tue           #Beverages                 52,6
14  A01  2  Tue           #Beverages                180,8
15  A01  2  Tue           #Beverages                124,4
16  A01  2  Tue          #Appliances                  542
17  A01  2  Tue          #Appliances               28.718
18  A01  2  Tue          #Appliances               35.308
19  A01  2  Tue          #Appliances                   99
20  A01  2  Tue  Avg.brewingduration                   38
21  A01  2  Tue  Avg.brewingduration                  665
22  A01  2  Tue  Avg.brewingduration                  676
23  A01  2  Tue  Avg.brewingduration                   10
```

Comment: Thanks! Er, so, I should fix my raw data by adding blank cells above the index column, then use the `melt` command as above?